# REGEX to validate excel like mathematical expressions

Tags: regex, excel-formula

I'd like to know how to create a regex to validate a function like this:

```
=TRIMESTER(1,2,2008)
```

The first parameter should be any integer.
The second parameter is an integer that shouldn't be higher than 4.
The third parameter is a year (4 digits)

Comment: Could you clarify on the first parameter, please?

Comment: Done. I described all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
=TRIMESTER\(\d+,[1-4],\d{4}\)
```

It matches any number of digits (at least one) for the first parameter, any digit between 1 and 4 (included) for the second and any four digits for the last one.

Or, if you want to validate only the second parameter, this:

```
[1-4]
```

but I would prefer simple comparison for that, like this:

```
AND(x >= 1; x <= 4)
```

Comment: I'm testing it but if I put a 2 or more digit on the first parameter I get false as the validation result.

Comment: In the original post I missed a `+`. I fixed it in the meanwhile. Perhaps you didn't notice that?